# Logo con enlace a index toma tambien el margen del logo

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy tratando de usar un logo con redirección al index,funciona, el logo lo tengo centrado con 0 auto, pero los margenes left y right tambien me los toma como parte del enlace,mi pregunta, como hacer que el enlace solo afecte el área de la imagen?

adjunto código:

```css
.nombre-sitio img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1 class="nombre-sitio"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></h1> 
</header>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que está en el código que compartes es diferente a lo que muestra la captura, como te indican en la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el código que has escrito es correcto, pero si te fijas en la parte del navegador has puesto antes el link que el `h1` por lo tanto el link está afectando a todo tu `h1`.

Para solucionarlo lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar la estructura como el codigo que has puesto antes

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="nombre-sitio">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </h1> 
</header>
```

Con esto debería de estar solucionado tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias,ahora si funciona y ya no se me va a olvidar jaja :D

Comment: De nada, te recomiendo que marques la respuesta como valida para cerrar la pregunta. Para hacer esto tienes que aceptar la respuesta, con el icono del tick.

Comment: @MatiasPerez En vez de añadir **"solucionado"** en tu título, sería bueno que aceptaras la pregunta que más te sirvió y ayudó a resolver tu problema, de esta forma tu pregunta estará como respondida, saludos.